# HTTP Headers causing IE problems?

Tags: internet-explorer, http

I have a strange problem I cannot track down. Users of internet explorer are reporting that IE throws a "page cannot be display" message after it finishes loading pages served with the following headers. They see the page briefly, but then it disappears and is replaced by the error page. It doesn't seem to matter what the contents of the page are. 
I seem to have tracked it down to these headers:

```
Expires: Fri, 13 Jan 2012 01:00:00 GMT
Date: Fri, 26 Oct 2012 02:02:33 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Last-modified: Fri, 26 Oct 2012 02:02:33 GMT
Cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0, pre-check=0, post-check=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

In most cases I have seen, the users seem to have their clocks running forward signifcantly from the server (upto half an hour). They all seem to be on IE8 running laptops. Any ideas? The server is also running on port 8181 instead of 80.

Comment: The Cache-control headers you have are *very* tight - especially "must-revalidate" and "max-age=0". Can those be loosened for testing? Out of 100 visits to pages with these headers, how many report this problem?

Comment: In particular, drop everything not defined in the HTTP spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out this was a problem with mcafee antivirus problem.

Answer (score 0):

How did you track it down to those headers (rather than the content of the html files)? I'd generally rather guess it's the content of the file(s). Have you tried a hand-written, simple `<html><body>hi</body></html>` style html page (with and without the optional headers of those you mentioned)?

If you have access to a client where the problem can be reproduced, I'd use **[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)** on the client to record the request(s) once, drag it(/them) over to the list in the **AutoResponder tab** on the right hand side (you need to `Enable automatic responses` first in order to be able to drop the request into the list) and then have Fiddler return the response, rather than the server, each time removing a single header, or changing the html, to narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, have you try to run your site without header? if it's work then you might need to change `pragma` header to `header ('Pragma: public');`.

Answer (score 0):

When Internet Explorer connects to a Web server and the IP address list returned from the DNS servers contains multiple IP addresses, Internet Explorer tries to make a TCP connection using these IP addresses in the order in which they were received. Once a TCP connection is successfully established, Internet Explorer uses that IP address to send the HTTP request to.

check the link below.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2293762